# Insert into One-To-One Tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

As you can see in the picture below, I have two tables. I dragged the ID From tblDriver To ID Of tblCar.[image: 1-1 Table]

In C#, I want to insert data into these empty tables. I can insert into tblDriver But tblCar gives me the error about foreign key. I Mean the first "ExecuteNonQuery" executes well but the second one gives the error.[image]

Should I or Can I insert into two tables at the same time?

Comment: Don't add code as image, insert code instead. Also mention the error you are receiving.

Comment: Why would the driver and car ids be the same? What about drivers with more than one car? Also you should be using parameters for all values in that query not just one of them.

Comment: ID isn't an autoincrement in both tables? You are not mentioning ID in both Inserts. How should they be connected if you don't mentioning them?

Comment: 1. ID's in both tables are Identity(autoincrement).

2. In My program, Each Driver Has Only ONE Car

Comment: why dont u try using stored procedure?it would be much easier

Answer (score 0):

If you've made a Key relationship between the tables, that means you've said one of those id's must match the other.

But right now, you are not inserting that matching id.

You need to insert them sequentially, not at the same time, if you want that relationship.
But you also need to capture the id from the first one and insert it in the second.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong. If you want to map driver ID in CAR table, Use a seperate foreign key column. A Driver can have 1 or more cars, But a car cannot have more than 1 driver. I hope so this is your scenario. If at all you want to make 1 driver has 1 car, make sure you enter driver into table and next enter the car into table with the ID of the driver. So as you want you will have the same car ID and Driver ID if and only if you want to make 1 driver has 1 car so that for every single entry of a driver there is a single entry of the car.

Comment: Sorry, Can you improve my SQL statement?
Should I still use two "INSERT INTO" statement?
My approach is 1 Driver , 1 Car.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to make use of [`@@IDENTITY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx) which generate from table `tblCar` to insert foreign ID value in table `tblDriver`.

Following code will help to solve your problem:

```
DataTable _dataTable = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter _dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand();

_cmd.Connection = connection;
_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblCar(ColumName) Values(value) select @@IDENTITY";
_dataAdapter.SelectCommand = _cmd;
//Here _dataTable will hold ID value from tblCar
_dataAdapter.Fill(_dataTable);

//Here insert same generated ID value in tblDriver
_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblDriver(@ID, ColumName) Values(value)";
_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", _dataTable.Rows[0][0]);
_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Sorry. But it doesn't work. One Error is  "Must declare the scalar variable "@img" which is for storing image.

And Also: What Is "@ID" in second INSERT INTO? should i change number of valus and column names? what is the first value in value list?

Comment: @ZobeyrFa `@ID` is: new ID generated from `tblCar`. Since you have relation between tables `tblCar` and `tblDriver` hence `ID` from required to insert into `tblDriver`, right? Actually here you pasted image of code rather than code hence I find difficult to match up with exact code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Guys.

According to the execution order of statements in c#, I only had to drag the key vice versa in SQL Server. Done!!!!

Your're great.